# How to select from explicit partition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In Oracle, MySQL  I can select from partition

```
SELECT ... FROM ... PARTITION (...)
```

In SQL Server syntax is a bit different involving partitioning function.

is there a way to do it in PostgreSQL?

thank you!

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM   product
    where  tableoid::regclass::text ='product_a'

Comment: SELECT t.*
    FROM   product   t
    JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.oid = t.tableoid
    JOIN   pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
    WHERE t.tableoid=16411

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL provided [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) through [table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html).

Partitions are child tables with an unique name like any other table, so you just select from them directly with their names. The only special case is for the parent table: to select data from the parent table ignoring the child tables, an additional keyword `ONLY` is used as in `SELECT * FROM ONLY parent_table`.

Example from the manual:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement_y2006m02 (
    CHECK ( logdate >= DATE '2006-02-01' AND logdate < DATE '2006-03-01' )
) INHERITS (measurement);
```

So `select * from measurement_y2006m02` would get data from only this partition.

Comment: Thank you, I can actually use it.

Comment: is there some way to call the parent table?